# How to change CSS of a dynamically generated DIV's id?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a DIV containing a loader gif picture :

... some php codes to get the $pdId

... while loop to generate dynamic li's

```
 echo'<li><div class="loadme" id="'.$pdId.'"><img id="qtyloading" src="../../images/loading_6.gif" width="160" height="160"/></div>


 .... some other codes

 </li>';
```

.....  end of the while loop

There is a textarea tag that will call the external js function  onBlur

```
  .... some codes here
  echo '<textarea  rows="3" cols="30" id="<separator>'.$ud.'<separator>'.$olue.'<separator>'.$pdId.'<separator>" onBlur="yorDesc(this.id,this.value)" >'.$deomer.'</textarea><br />';
```

and here is the external js file

```
    ... some codes to get the id 
alert (gid);
document.getElementById("'+gid+'").style.display = "block";
```

the  gid var is the ID of the loadme div, as you see I am alerting it and it showes the correct ID being parsed, and of course  you have noticed that the loadme div being generated dynamically with different IDs.  I supposed that I would be able to have access to each individual loader DIV by using the above mentioned javascript code, but I am not.

Could you help me to find out why? Ask me if any part of the above code or description is not clear for you I will edit it.

Appreciated.

Comment: How about adding class in the div and styling accordingly.

Comment: Is gid is string or HTMLElement if string then use like document.getElementById(gid).style.display = "block"; or gid.style.display= "block"

Comment: @Nilambar its generated dynamically, I don't have access to each one of the separately, all the divs will be block if I change the css trough the fix class name. that's what I don't need

Comment: @RajaJaganathan gid is an int number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById(gid.toString()).style.display = "block";
```

**This will do the trick.**  Or you can use `(''+gid+'')` if you prefer.  You almost had it, just mixed too many different quotes together.

Comment: you are AWESOME, It's an H I am sitting and twisting the code  gid.toString()   is the answer. brilliant really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If it is id then you can use like.works well.

```
document.getElementById(gid).style.backgroundColor="red";
```

In your case need not worry about dynamically created div through PHP.

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7p6K9/1/)

Comment: no this is not correct, the external function is being called onBlur  how do I know which div has been called if I use your code, your code is changing the colour of the div with div number 2 only. what if div number 4 should be changed ??? you are setting the attr manually

Comment: @user3150692 updated. ok once you got id from onBlur event then what you want to do.